# Error in installing ZTE AC2738 on ubuntu 3.0.0-12-generic

Tags: 64-bit, zte

I am getting this error ,`struct usb_serial_driver has no member named shutdown`.
I am installing on 64bit `ubuntu 3.0.0-12-generic`

```
... Beginning Verify CD ... 
... Verify CD Succeed! 
... Beginning Copy Install Package Files ... 
    ... will take a long time, waiting 5 seconds, please
... Copy Install Package Files Succeed! 

... 'ztemtApp' previous version not found. and install now 
Beginning install ... 
... Current linux release version is 'Ubuntu' 
... Checking 'App' process  
... Checking old installation 
... Installing ... 
Current Path is : . :  /tmp/ztemt_datacard/Linux
1. Checking Previous Version ... 
2. Copying Data Bin ... 
    ... will take a few seconds, please waiting ...
/tmp/ztemt_datacard/Linux
3. Auto Load Usb Driver Module ... 
Rather than invoking init scripts through /etc/init.d, use the service(8)
utility, e.g. service acpid restart

Since the script you are attempting to invoke has been converted to an
Upstart job, you may also use the stop(8) and then start(8) utilities,
e.g. stop acpid ; start acpid. The restart(8) utility is also available.
acpid stop/waiting
acpid start/running, process 11802
4. Changing pppd Options ... 
5. Changing File Permission ... 
6. Deleting Qt lib When Local QT Vertion > V4.4.0 ... 
    ... Package 'libqtgui4' exist
    ... QT_VERSION = 4
7. Deleting process id file: EVDOApp.pid ... 
8. Making USB Serial Driver Module : ztemt.ko ... 
    ... will take a few seconds, please waiting ...
make -C /lib/modules/3.0.0-12-generic/build             M=/usr/local/bin/ztemtApp/zteusbserial/below2.6.27 modules
make[1]: Entering directory `/usr/src/linux-headers-3.0.0-12-generic'
  CC [M]  /usr/local/bin/ztemtApp/zteusbserial/below2.6.27/usb-serial.o
/usr/local/bin/ztemtApp/zteusbserial/below2.6.27/usb-serial.c: In function ‘destroy_serial’:
/usr/local/bin/ztemtApp/zteusbserial/below2.6.27/usb-serial.c:159:14: error: ‘struct usb_serial_driver’ has no member named ‘shutdown’
/usr/local/bin/ztemtApp/zteusbserial/below2.6.27/usb-serial.c:165:18: error: ‘struct usb_serial_port’ has no member named ‘open_count’
/usr/local/bin/ztemtApp/zteusbserial/below2.6.27/usb-serial.c: In function ‘serial_open’:
/usr/local/bin/ztemtApp/zteusbserial/below2.6.27/usb-serial.c:241:36: error: ‘struct usb_serial_port’ has no member named ‘mutex’
/usr/local/bin/ztemtApp/zteusbserial/below2.6.27/usb-serial.c:246:8: error: ‘struct usb_serial_port’ has no member named ‘open_count’
/usr/local/bin/ztemtApp/zteusbserial/below2.6.27/usb-serial.c:251:6: error: ‘struct usb_serial_port’ has no member named ‘tty’
/usr/local/bin/ztemtApp/zteusbserial/below2.6.27/usb-serial.c:253:10: error: ‘struct usb_serial_port’ has no member named ‘open_count’
/usr/local/bin/ztemtApp/zteusbserial/below2.6.27/usb-serial.c:265:3: warning: passing argument 1 of ‘serial->type->open’ from incompatible pointer type [enabled by default]
/usr/local/bin/ztemtApp/zteusbserial/below2.6.27/usb-serial.c:265:3: note: expected ‘struct tty_struct *’ but argument is of type ‘struct usb_serial_port *’
/usr/local/bin/ztemtApp/zteusbserial/below2.6.27/usb-serial.c:265:3: warning: passing argument 2 of ‘serial->type->open’ from incompatible pointer type [enabled by default]
/usr/local/bin/ztemtApp/zteusbserial/below2.6.27/usb-serial.c:265:3: note: expected ‘struct usb_serial_port *’ but argument is of type ‘struct file *’
/usr/local/bin/ztemtApp/zteusbserial/below2.6.27/usb-serial.c:270:20: error: ‘struct usb_serial_port’ has no member named ‘mutex’
/usr/local/bin/ztemtApp/zteusbserial/below2.6.27/usb-serial.c:276:6: error: ‘struct usb_serial_port’ has no member named ‘open_count’
/usr/local/bin/ztemtApp/zteusbserial/below2.6.27/usb-serial.c:278:6: error: ‘struct usb_serial_port’ has no member named ‘tty’
/usr/local/bin/ztemtApp/zteusbserial/below2.6.27/usb-serial.c:279:20: error: ‘struct usb_serial_port’ has no member named ‘mutex’
/usr/local/bin/ztemtApp/zteusbserial/below2.6.27/usb-serial.c: In function ‘serial_close’:
/usr/local/bin/ztemtApp/zteusbserial/below2.6.27/usb-serial.c:355:18: error: ‘struct usb_serial_port’ has no member named ‘mutex’
/usr/local/bin/ztemtApp/zteusbserial/below2.6.27/usb-serial.c:357:10: error: ‘struct usb_serial_port’ has no member named ‘open_count’
/usr/local/bin/ztemtApp/zteusbserial/below2.6.27/usb-serial.c:358:21: error: ‘struct usb_serial_port’ has no member named ‘mutex’
/usr/local/bin/ztemtApp/zteusbserial/below2.6.27/usb-serial.c:371:8: error: ‘struct usb_serial_port’ has no member named ‘open_count’
/usr/local/bin/ztemtApp/zteusbserial/below2.6.27/usb-serial.c:372:10: error: ‘struct usb_serial_port’ has no member named ‘open_count’
/usr/local/bin/ztemtApp/zteusbserial/below2.6.27/usb-serial.c:375:3: error: too many arguments to function ‘port->serial->type->close’
/usr/local/bin/ztemtApp/zteusbserial/below2.6.27/usb-serial.c:377:11: error: ‘struct usb_serial_port’ has no member named ‘tty’
/usr/local/bin/ztemtApp/zteusbserial/below2.6.27/usb-serial.c:378:12: error: ‘struct usb_serial_port’ has no member named ‘tty’
/usr/local/bin/ztemtApp/zteusbserial/below2.6.27/usb-serial.c:379:9: error: ‘struct usb_serial_port’ has no member named ‘tty’
/usr/local/bin/ztemtApp/zteusbserial/below2.6.27/usb-serial.c:380:8: error: ‘struct usb_serial_port’ has no member named ‘tty’
/usr/local/bin/ztemtApp/zteusbserial/below2.6.27/usb-serial.c:386:20: error: ‘struct usb_serial_port’ has no member named ‘mutex’
/usr/local/bin/ztemtApp/zteusbserial/below2.6.27/usb-serial.c: In function ‘serial_write’:
/usr/local/bin/ztemtApp/zteusbserial/below2.6.27/usb-serial.c:407:11: error: ‘struct usb_serial_port’ has no member named ‘open_count’
/usr/local/bin/ztemtApp/zteusbserial/below2.6.27/usb-serial.c:413:2: warning: passing argument 1 of ‘port->serial->type->write’ from incompatible pointer type [enabled by default]
/usr/local/bin/ztemtApp/zteusbserial/below2.6.27/usb-serial.c:413:2: note: expected ‘struct tty_struct *’ but argument is of type ‘struct usb_serial_port *’
/usr/local/bin/ztemtApp/zteusbserial/below2.6.27/usb-serial.c:413:2: warning: passing argument 2 of ‘port->serial->type->write’ from incompatible pointer type [enabled by default]
/usr/local/bin/ztemtApp/zteusbserial/below2.6.27/usb-serial.c:413:2: note: expected ‘struct usb_serial_port *’ but argument is of type ‘const unsigned char *’
/usr/local/bin/ztemtApp/zteusbserial/below2.6.27/usb-serial.c:413:2: warning: passing argument 3 of ‘port->serial->type->write’ makes pointer from integer without a cast [enabled by default]
/usr/local/bin/ztemtApp/zteusbserial/below2.6.27/usb-serial.c:413:2: note: expected ‘const unsigned char *’ but argument is of type ‘int’
/usr/local/bin/ztemtApp/zteusbserial/below2.6.27/usb-serial.c:413:2: error: too few arguments to function ‘port->serial->type->write’
/usr/local/bin/ztemtApp/zteusbserial/below2.6.27/usb-serial.c: In function ‘serial_write_room’:
/usr/local/bin/ztemtApp/zteusbserial/below2.6.27/usb-serial.c:429:11: error: ‘struct usb_serial_port’ has no member named ‘open_count’
/usr/local/bin/ztemtApp/zteusbserial/below2.6.27/usb-serial.c:435:2: warning: passing argument 1 of ‘port->serial->type->write_room’ from incompatible pointer type [enabled by default]
/usr/local/bin/ztemtApp/zteusbserial/below2.6.27/usb-serial.c:435:2: note: expected ‘struct tty_struct *’ but argument is of type ‘struct usb_serial_port *’
/usr/local/bin/ztemtApp/zteusbserial/below2.6.27/usb-serial.c: In function ‘serial_chars_in_buffer’:
/usr/local/bin/ztemtApp/zteusbserial/below2.6.27/usb-serial.c:451:11: error: ‘struct usb_serial_port’ has no member named ‘open_count’
/usr/local/bin/ztemtApp/zteusbserial/below2.6.27/usb-serial.c:457:2: warning: passing argument 1 of ‘port->serial->type->chars_in_buffer’ from incompatible pointer type [enabled by default]
/usr/local/bin/ztemtApp/zteusbserial/below2.6.27/usb-serial.c:457:2: note: expected ‘struct tty_struct *’ but argument is of type ‘struct usb_serial_port *’
/usr/local/bin/ztemtApp/zteusbserial/below2.6.27/usb-serial.c: In function ‘serial_throttle’:
/usr/local/bin/ztemtApp/zteusbserial/below2.6.27/usb-serial.c:472:11: error: ‘struct usb_serial_port’ has no member named ‘open_count’
/usr/local/bin/ztemtApp/zteusbserial/below2.6.27/usb-serial.c:479:3: warning: passing argument 1 of ‘port->serial->type->throttle’ from incompatible pointer type [enabled by default]
/usr/local/bin/ztemtApp/zteusbserial/below2.6.27/usb-serial.c:479:3: note: expected ‘struct tty_struct *’ but argument is of type ‘struct usb_serial_port *’
/usr/local/bin/ztemtApp/zteusbserial/below2.6.27/usb-serial.c: In function ‘serial_unthrottle’:
/usr/local/bin/ztemtApp/zteusbserial/below2.6.27/usb-serial.c:491:11: error: ‘struct usb_serial_port’ has no member named ‘open_count’
/usr/local/bin/ztemtApp/zteusbserial/below2.6.27/usb-serial.c:498:3: warning: passing argument 1 of ‘port->serial->type->unthrottle’ from incompatible pointer type [enabled by default]
/usr/local/bin/ztemtApp/zteusbserial/below2.6.27/usb-serial.c:498:3: note: expected ‘struct tty_struct *’ but argument is of type ‘struct usb_serial_port *’
/usr/local/bin/ztemtApp/zteusbserial/below2.6.27/usb-serial.c: In function ‘serial_ioctl’:
/usr/local/bin/ztemtApp/zteusbserial/below2.6.27/usb-serial.c:511:11: error: ‘struct usb_serial_port’ has no member named ‘open_count’
/usr/local/bin/ztemtApp/zteusbserial/below2.6.27/usb-serial.c:518:3: warning: passing argument 1 of ‘port->serial->type->ioctl’ from incompatible pointer type [enabled by default]
/usr/local/bin/ztemtApp/zteusbserial/below2.6.27/usb-serial.c:518:3: note: expected ‘struct tty_struct *’ but argument is of type ‘struct usb_serial_port *’
/usr/local/bin/ztemtApp/zteusbserial/below2.6.27/usb-serial.c:518:3: warning: passing argument 2 of ‘port->serial->type->ioctl’ makes integer from pointer without a cast [enabled by default]
/usr/local/bin/ztemtApp/zteusbserial/below2.6.27/usb-serial.c:518:3: note: expected ‘unsigned int’ but argument is of type ‘struct file *’
/usr/local/bin/ztemtApp/zteusbserial/below2.6.27/usb-serial.c:518:3: error: too many arguments to function ‘port->serial->type->ioctl’
/usr/local/bin/ztemtApp/zteusbserial/below2.6.27/usb-serial.c: In function ‘serial_set_termios’:
/usr/local/bin/ztemtApp/zteusbserial/below2.6.27/usb-serial.c:535:11: error: ‘struct usb_serial_port’ has no member named ‘open_count’
/usr/local/bin/ztemtApp/zteusbserial/below2.6.27/usb-serial.c:542:3: warning: passing argument 1 of ‘port->serial->type->set_termios’ from incompatible pointer type [enabled by default]
/usr/local/bin/ztemtApp/zteusbserial/below2.6.27/usb-serial.c:542:3: note: expected ‘struct tty_struct *’ but argument is of type ‘struct usb_serial_port *’
/usr/local/bin/ztemtApp/zteusbserial/below2.6.27/usb-serial.c:542:3: warning: passing argument 2 of ‘port->serial->type->set_termios’ from incompatible pointer type [enabled by default]
/usr/local/bin/ztemtApp/zteusbserial/below2.6.27/usb-serial.c:542:3: note: expected ‘struct usb_serial_port *’ but argument is of type ‘struct termios *’
/usr/local/bin/ztemtApp/zteusbserial/below2.6.27/usb-serial.c:542:3: error: too few arguments to function ‘port->serial->type->set_termios’
/usr/local/bin/ztemtApp/zteusbserial/below2.6.27/usb-serial.c: In function ‘serial_break’:
/usr/local/bin/ztemtApp/zteusbserial/below2.6.27/usb-serial.c:554:11: error: ‘struct usb_serial_port’ has no member named ‘open_count’
/usr/local/bin/ztemtApp/zteusbserial/below2.6.27/usb-serial.c:561:3: warning: passing argument 1 of ‘port->serial->type->break_ctl’ from incompatible pointer type [enabled by default]
/usr/local/bin/ztemtApp/zteusbserial/below2.6.27/usb-serial.c:561:3: note: expected ‘struct tty_struct *’ but argument is of type ‘struct usb_serial_port *’
/usr/local/bin/ztemtApp/zteusbserial/below2.6.27/usb-serial.c: In function ‘serial_tiocmget’:
/usr/local/bin/ztemtApp/zteusbserial/below2.6.27/usb-serial.c:629:11: error: ‘struct usb_serial_port’ has no member named ‘open_count’
/usr/local/bin/ztemtApp/zteusbserial/below2.6.27/usb-serial.c:635:3: warning: passing argument 1 of ‘port->serial->type->tiocmget’ from incompatible pointer type [enabled by default]
/usr/local/bin/ztemtApp/zteusbserial/below2.6.27/usb-serial.c:635:3: note: expected ‘struct tty_struct *’ but argument is of type ‘struct usb_serial_port *’
/usr/local/bin/ztemtApp/zteusbserial/below2.6.27/usb-serial.c:635:3: error: too many arguments to function ‘port->serial->type->tiocmget’
/usr/local/bin/ztemtApp/zteusbserial/below2.6.27/usb-serial.c: In function ‘serial_tiocmset’:
/usr/local/bin/ztemtApp/zteusbserial/below2.6.27/usb-serial.c:651:11: error: ‘struct usb_serial_port’ has no member named ‘open_count’
/usr/local/bin/ztemtApp/zteusbserial/below2.6.27/usb-serial.c:657:3: warning: passing argument 1 of ‘port->serial->type->tiocmset’ from incompatible pointer type [enabled by default]
/usr/local/bin/ztemtApp/zteusbserial/below2.6.27/usb-serial.c:657:3: note: expected ‘struct tty_struct *’ but argument is of type ‘struct usb_serial_port *’
/usr/local/bin/ztemtApp/zteusbserial/below2.6.27/usb-serial.c:657:3: warning: passing argument 2 of ‘port->serial->type->tiocmset’ makes integer from pointer without a cast [enabled by default]
/usr/local/bin/ztemtApp/zteusbserial/below2.6.27/usb-serial.c:657:3: note: expected ‘unsigned int’ but argument is of type ‘struct file *’
/usr/local/bin/ztemtApp/zteusbserial/below2.6.27/usb-serial.c:657:3: error: too many arguments to function ‘port->serial->type->tiocmset’
/usr/local/bin/ztemtApp/zteusbserial/below2.6.27/usb-serial.c: In function ‘usb_serial_port_work’:
/usr/local/bin/ztemtApp/zteusbserial/below2.6.27/usb-serial.c:697:12: error: ‘struct usb_serial_port’ has no member named ‘tty’
/usr/local/bin/ztemtApp/zteusbserial/below2.6.27/usb-serial.c: In function ‘port_release’:
/usr/local/bin/ztemtApp/zteusbserial/below2.6.27/usb-serial.c:709:2: error: ‘struct device’ has no member named ‘bus_id’
/usr/local/bin/ztemtApp/zteusbserial/below2.6.27/usb-serial.c: In function ‘usb_serial_probe’:
/usr/local/bin/ztemtApp/zteusbserial/below2.6.27/usb-serial.c:858:2: error: implicit declaration of function ‘lock_kernel’ [-Werror=implicit-function-declaration]
/usr/local/bin/ztemtApp/zteusbserial/below2.6.27/usb-serial.c:861:3: error: implicit declaration of function ‘unlock_kernel’ [-Werror=implicit-function-declaration]
/usr/local/bin/ztemtApp/zteusbserial/below2.6.27/usb-serial.c:1034:3: error: ‘struct usb_serial_port’ has no member named ‘mutex’
/usr/local/bin/ztemtApp/zteusbserial/below2.6.27/usb-serial.c:1182:23: error: ‘struct device’ has no member named ‘bus_id’
/usr/local/bin/ztemtApp/zteusbserial/below2.6.27/usb-serial.c:1182:51: error: ‘struct device’ has no member named ‘bus_id’
/usr/local/bin/ztemtApp/zteusbserial/below2.6.27/usb-serial.c:1183:3: error: ‘struct device’ has no member named ‘bus_id’
/usr/local/bin/ztemtApp/zteusbserial/below2.6.27/usb-serial.c: In function ‘usb_serial_disconnect’:
/usr/local/bin/ztemtApp/zteusbserial/below2.6.27/usb-serial.c:1257:13: error: ‘struct usb_serial_port’ has no member named ‘tty’
/usr/local/bin/ztemtApp/zteusbserial/below2.6.27/usb-serial.c:1258:21: error: ‘struct usb_serial_port’ has no member named ‘tty’
/usr/local/bin/ztemtApp/zteusbserial/below2.6.27/usb-serial.c: At top level:
/usr/local/bin/ztemtApp/zteusbserial/below2.6.27/usb-serial.c:1280:2: warning: initialization from incompatible pointer type [enabled by default]
/usr/local/bin/ztemtApp/zteusbserial/below2.6.27/usb-serial.c:1280:2: warning: (near initialization for ‘serial_ops.ioctl’) [enabled by default]
/usr/local/bin/ztemtApp/zteusbserial/below2.6.27/usb-serial.c:1281:2: warning: initialization from incompatible pointer type [enabled by default]
/usr/local/bin/ztemtApp/zteusbserial/below2.6.27/usb-serial.c:1281:2: warning: (near initialization for ‘serial_ops.set_termios’) [enabled by default]
/usr/local/bin/ztemtApp/zteusbserial/below2.6.27/usb-serial.c:1284:2: warning: initialization from incompatible pointer type [enabled by default]
/usr/local/bin/ztemtApp/zteusbserial/below2.6.27/usb-serial.c:1284:2: warning: (near initialization for ‘serial_ops.break_ctl’) [enabled by default]
/usr/local/bin/ztemtApp/zteusbserial/below2.6.27/usb-serial.c:1286:2: error: unknown field ‘read_proc’ specified in initializer
/usr/local/bin/ztemtApp/zteusbserial/below2.6.27/usb-serial.c:1286:2: warning: initialization from incompatible pointer type [enabled by default]
/usr/local/bin/ztemtApp/zteusbserial/below2.6.27/usb-serial.c:1286:2: warning: (near initialization for ‘serial_ops.ioctl’) [enabled by default]
/usr/local/bin/ztemtApp/zteusbserial/below2.6.27/usb-serial.c:1287:2: warning: initialization from incompatible pointer type [enabled by default]
/usr/local/bin/ztemtApp/zteusbserial/below2.6.27/usb-serial.c:1287:2: warning: (near initialization for ‘serial_ops.tiocmget’) [enabled by default]
/usr/local/bin/ztemtApp/zteusbserial/below2.6.27/usb-serial.c:1288:2: warning: initialization from incompatible pointer type [enabled by default]
/usr/local/bin/ztemtApp/zteusbserial/below2.6.27/usb-serial.c:1288:2: warning: (near initialization for ‘serial_ops.tiocmset’) [enabled by default]
/usr/local/bin/ztemtApp/zteusbserial/below2.6.27/usb-serial.c: In function ‘usb_serial_init’:
/usr/local/bin/ztemtApp/zteusbserial/below2.6.27/usb-serial.c:1352:2: error: implicit declaration of function ‘info’ [-Werror=implicit-function-declaration]
/usr/local/bin/ztemtApp/zteusbserial/below2.6.27/usb-serial.c: In function ‘fixup_generic’:
/usr/local/bin/ztemtApp/zteusbserial/below2.6.27/usb-serial.c:1406:2: error: ‘struct usb_serial_driver’ has no member named ‘shutdown’
/usr/local/bin/ztemtApp/zteusbserial/below2.6.27/usb-serial.c:1406:2: error: ‘struct usb_serial_driver’ has no member named ‘shutdown’
/usr/local/bin/ztemtApp/zteusbserial/below2.6.27/usb-serial.c:1406:1: error: ‘usb_serial_generic_shutdown’ undeclared (first use in this function)
/usr/local/bin/ztemtApp/zteusbserial/below2.6.27/usb-serial.c:1406:1: note: each undeclared identifier is reported only once for each function it appears in
cc1: some warnings being treated as errors

make[2]: *** [/usr/local/bin/ztemtApp/zteusbserial/below2.6.27/usb-serial.o] Error 1
make[1]: *** [_module_/usr/local/bin/ztemtApp/zteusbserial/below2.6.27] Error 2
make[1]: Leaving directory `/usr/src/linux-headers-3.0.0-12-generic'
make: *** [modules] Error 2
Install finished!
```

Any suggestion?

Update: from installation document , `In some special cases, the setup package can’t automatically compile the driver, so you
need change the configurations yourself and manually compile the driver.
Method: enter the directory: /usr/local/bin/ztemtApp/zteusbserial, and find the corresponding kernel version of current system.`
I can see `2.6.27  2.6.28  2.6.29  2.6.30  2.6.31  2.6.32  2.6.33  2.6.34  2.6.35  2.6.36  2.6.37  2.6.38  2.6.39  below2.6.2` in the directory. Which version shall I pick up for installation? Readme file says, we have to do this to insert `ztemt.ko` in kernel.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you are installing 64 bit software only for your OS is alos 64bit.

ZTE must have provided you with some installer, most probably with name of
**something_amd64.deb** or **something_i686.deb** 
or alternatively a tar bal **something.tar.gz**
If not then check the company's website if they something up for download or in their ppa

Just throw up terminal <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>T</kbd> and follow the command

```
sudo dpkg -i something.deb
sudo apt-get install -f
```

Note: here I assume thei nstaller's  name to be **something**
Hope this helps

Comment: Hi, there is no deb file. It compiling code on my machine. According to google results for error, I believe this is related to 64bit or kernel version problem. See the update.

Comment: i strongly believe that what you are installing is 32bit agains your 64bit OS... i faced the same problem once that the 32 bit app got installed on 64bit OS but never ran. hope this is the same case. if the company is not providing anything then i am afraid u have to depend upon some generic drivers

Comment: right now the driver is not compiling. I have to configure through  network connections and it is working.

Answer (score 0):

Try to purge the directories and clean the place where the package is going to be installed.

you can use BleachBit software for this and also do 
sudo apt-get purge && sudo apt-get clean &&sudo apt-get autoclean

Then install the package from the deb or tar.gz archive via dpkg..

you can also ask for the company for support or for their **ppa**

Answer (score 0):

I am writing this with a ZTE2738 on 12.04. I also got some issues as you mentioned above. Now, i am using it nicely. As you updated, this can be done through network manager by adding Mobile Broadband with #777 as dialer number and your id, passwd as your mobile number. But the problem is, you cannot select different speed settings like: Hybrid, 1x, etc. So the default speed will be selected. 
  Now about your problem. Are you sure about that you already installed modeprobe, usbmodeswitch, usbserial? If so you should try make and make-install. Otherwise check for .sh file in the folder and execute it.